# Colocar um EditText no DialogFragment

Tags: android

Preciso colocar um EditText para poder preencher o nome... ou seja quando o usuário clicar no botão aparecerá uma AlertDialog, que devera colocar o nome do jogador, fiz ate um passo, aqui no SOpt tem uma pergunta desse tipo só que não conseguir solucionar.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Código:

```
package com.gif.popupsair;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

public class MyCaixa extends DialogFragment{

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builderr = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builderr.setMessage("Nome do jogador")
                .setPositiveButton("Salvar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        builderr.setTitle("Golll!");
        AlertDialog dialog = builderr.create();

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nathan,

Vou te dar uma sugestão um pouco melhor. O que foi feito na resposta acima da @Eduarda pode ser feito sem necessariamente herdar de `Dialog`. O `AlertDialog` possui um método chamado `setView()`, onde você pode inserir uma view costumizada por você.

Faremos isso dentro do próprio método `onCreateDialog` assim:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.seulayoutcustomizado, null);
builderr.setView(view);
```

Segue o código completo:

```
package com.gif.popupsair;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

public class MyCaixa extends DialogFragment{

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builderr = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builderr.setMessage("Nome do jogador")
                .setPositiveButton("Salvar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        builderr.setTitle("Golll!");

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.seulayoutcustomizado, null);
        builderr.setView(view);

        AlertDialog dialog = builderr.create();

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Não é aconselhável a usar `Dialog` fora de um `DialogFragment`, como a resposta da @Eduarda faz. Isso porque se o seu `Dialog` for exibido atráves de um `DialogFragment`, ele vai estar melhor ligado ao ciclo de vida de uma `Activity`. Experimente em modo de depuração exibir um `Dialog` sem um `DialogFragment` e rotacionar a tela. Você vai ver nos logs um erro assim :

> Activity x has leaked window com.android....DecorView

Isso porque ocorreu um vazamento por você não ter fechado o `Dialog` quando a `Activity` foi destruida durante a rotação. O que estou querendo dizer é que se você exibe um `Dialog` por conta própria, tem que atá-lo no ciclo de vida da `Activity` para que nenhum vazamento ocorra. Quando você usar o `DialogFragment`, esse tipo de preocupação não é necessária, pois é automático.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica...

Answer (score 1):

Como sugestão, você poderia utilizar um Dialog e definir o EditText no XML.

```
 public class MyCaixa extends Dialog {

    public MyCaixa(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
     }
}
```

E para chamar o Dialog basta:

```
new MyCaixa(context).show();
```